# Flexbox: Have item expand to fill row

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to modify my layout on mobile using flexbox and running into an issue. I would like for the middle box (2) to be rendered on its own line at 100% width on mobile. I used `order: 1` to move the box to the end, but now I can't figure out how to display the box at full width.

[image]

```css
.left, .middle, .right {
  background-color: rgba(84, 97, 156, 0.2);
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: rgb(84, 97, 156);
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  flex-grow: 1;
 }
 
.middle {
  text-align: center;
  order: 1;
}

.table-row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-row">
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="middle">2</div>
  <div class="right">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex-wrap:wrap on the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can resize the viewable area https://jsfiddle.net/mtukb38r/

```css
.table-row {
  display: flex;
}

.left, 
.middle, 
.right {
  background-color: rgba(84, 97, 156, 0.2);
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: rgb(84, 97, 156);
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  flex-grow: 1;
 }
 
.middle {
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)  {
  .table-row {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .middle {
    text-align: center;
    order: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table-row">
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="middle">2</div>
  <div class="right">3</div>
</div>
```

basically it's this on desktop

```css
.table-row {
  display: flex;
}

.left, 
.middle, 
.right {
  background-color: rgba(84, 97, 156, 0.2);
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: rgb(84, 97, 156);
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  flex-grow: 1;
 }
 
.middle {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-row">
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="middle">2</div>
  <div class="right">3</div>
</div>
```

and this on mobile

```css
.table-row {
  display: flex;
}

.left, 
.middle, 
.right {
  background-color: rgba(84, 97, 156, 0.2);
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: rgb(84, 97, 156);
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  flex-grow: 1;
 }
 
.middle {
  text-align: center;
}

.table-row {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.middle {
  text-align: center;
  order: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-row">
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="middle">2</div>
  <div class="right">3</div>
</div>
```